# Changing background toolbar colour and text colour in tinymce editor

Tags: javascript, css, tinymce, tinymce-4

I have used this code in my init call for tinymce to point at my main css file:

```
<script>
            tinymce.init({
                selector: 'textarea',
                content_css:'default.css'
            });
```

This works well and within that CSS i use this to alter the background colour of the body of my editor :

```
.mce-content-body {
background: #474F52;
}
```

I now want to add to this the appropriate CSS overrides for the toolbar colour - the button colour and the text colour as per:

[image: editor currently]

Please help! I have searched far and wide to no avail.

Comment: Are you just looking for the right CSS selectors to be able to change different elements? You should be able to use any web browsers inspector to see that

Comment: Yeah! I have tried but I actually cannot seem to find them.... The class appears to be : mce-container-body mce-flow-layout however this is the same as my CSS I have already altered - adding mce-flow-layout changes nothing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
/* toolbar */
.mce-toolbar-grp {
    background-color: #000 !important; /* uses !important or override .mce-panel background-color/image */
    background-image: none !important;
}

/* text color */
#tinymce {
   color: #dd9900;
}

/* button text color */
.mce-ico {
   color: #dd9900;
}

/* button background color */
.mce-btn button {
    background-color: #000000;
}
```

Comment: In fact this still does not change the toolbar colour...it remains the same original colour...even after altering the backround-color entry of the mce-toolbar-grp

Comment: you need to remove the background-image too, because by default it uses background-image not background-color... that's why I used `background-image: none;` above

Comment: If i use exactly what you have - with background-color set to a different colour - it does _not_ change it.