# Tinymce Angular7: Not loading custom css file via content_css property

Tags: css, tinymce, angular7

**How do I load custom CSS file to use with content_css property?**

I have been searching around the web, but I can't seem to get the answer to this question or at least I couldn't understand it.

So I have a public editorConfig obj which gets called in the init function of the HTML

```
<editor 
  [init]="editorConfig"
  [(ngModel)]="articleObj.text" name="text" id="text"
  (ngModelChange)="onChangeWordCount()">
</editor >

public editorConfig = {
    plugins: 'lists advlist image code media link table wordcount',
    menubar: false,
    statusbar: false,
    branding: false,
    browser_spellcheck: true, 
    content_css: 'src/assets/content.css',
```

This loads TinyMCE and my editor works great. I followed the docs and the scripts load with the lazy loading.

```
"assets": [
    "src/favicon.ico",
     "src/assets",
      { "glob": "**/*", "input": "node_modules/tinymce/skins", "output": "/skins/" },
      { "glob": "**/*", "input": "node_modules/tinymce/themes", "output": "/themes/" },
      { "glob": "**/*", "input": "node_modules/tinymce/plugins", "output": "/plugins/" }
 ],
```

However, I am not able to load my src/assets/content.css file. I keep getting a 404 (file not found).

I have added the path to my angular.json file

```
"styles": [
    "src/styles.scss",
   "src/assets/content.css"
],
```

**--- Update ---**

I updated the angular.json file:

```
"assets": [
    "src/favicon.ico",
    "src/assets",
    { "glob": "**/*", "input": "node_modules/tinymce/skins", "output": "/skins/" },
    { "glob": "**/*", "input": "node_modules/tinymce/themes", "output": "/themes/" },
    { "glob": "**/*", "input": "node_modules/tinymce/plugins", "output": "/plugins/" },
    { "glob": "**/*", "input": "src/assets", "output": "/src/assets" }
   ],
   "styles": [
     "src/styles.scss"
   ],
```

Then in the editor component, I am updating content_css property as:

```
content_css: 'src/assets/content.css',
```

Now the file is getting loaded and I am no longer getting a 404.
However, my CSS code doesn't seem to update the toolbar as I wanted. The change I was hoping for, was to change the toolbar background color.

**CSS Code**

```
/* toolbar */
.mce-toolbar-grp {
    background-color:#efeeee !important; /* uses !important or override .mce-panel background-color/image */
    background-image: none !important;
}
```

Which I got from here: [Changing background toolbar colour and text colour in tinymce editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24642448/changing-background-toolbar-colour-and-text-colour-in-tinymce-editor/24642595)

In short, I am not sure if my CSS is wrong or is the configuration/loading of the file which is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Old question but for those interested, above fail is due to the fact that you can't use a scss here. You need to convert it to css before.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are loading your `content_css` from a relative URL. When you enter a relative URL for `content_css`, it is resolved in relation to the URL of the HTML file that includes TinyMCE, not relative to TinyMCE itself ([source](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-appearance/#content_css)).

So, your URL of `src/assets/content.css` is getting called as `http://example.com/src/assets/content.css`.

You can either set the `content_css` part of your config to where that CSS file will be *after* it is outputted from the bundler, or host that CSS file outside of the bundling process, and set its URL directly.

Comment: I have updated the question if you could have look?